# C# - Cannot cast entity interface to entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

I have the following code:

```
public class CoursesController : ApiController
{
    private ITanulmanyokEntities _entities;

    public CoursesController()
        : this(new TanulmanyokEntities()) // ERROR HERE
    {
    }
    public CoursesController(ITanulmanyokEntities entities)
    {
        if (entities == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entities");

        _entities = entities;
    }

}
```

Here, I made an interface:

```
public interface ITanulmanyokEntities : IDisposable
{
    Int32 SaveChanges();

    DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    DbSet<EducationSubject> EducationSubjects { get; set; }
    DbSet<EducationUser> EducationUsers { get; set; }
    DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }

}
```

Which is supposed to be an interface for the entity generated from the database:

```
public partial class TanulmanyokEntities : DbContext
{
    public TanulmanyokEntities()
        : base("name=TanulmanyokEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EducationSubject> EducationSubjects { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<EducationUser> EducationUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }
}
```

However, I can't seem to convert one into the other. See commented row. The issue is, that my compiler cannot convert the interface/real thing. I think I implemented all that has to be implemented (I'm also following a pice of example code that works). What am I missing?

Comment: You cannot convert TanulmanyokEntities to ITanulmanyokEntities because it doesn't implement the interface. What is that interface for ?

Comment: It's an interface for `TanulmanyokEntities`. The example code by the teacher is EXACTLY the same, and it works for him... I'm running that code right now.

Comment: Can you post the example link ?

Comment: It's not a link, it's a whole project in a compressed file. But I can link it, if you wish.

Comment: @anserk Oh OK I've found it... He creates his own partial class to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that TanulmanyokEntities implements ITanulmanyokEntities

public partial class TanulmanyokEntities : DbContext,ITanulmanyokEntities

Comment: I don't think this is right. First, my example code works without that declaration, and also, `TanulmanyokEntities` is auto-generated and comes with a warning, too : `This code was generated from a template. ////Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application`

Comment: Ah.. I bet your not using code first.  The TanulmanyokEntities class that is generated is a Partial class so you can add a file that declares the interface like in the code above.  c# Partial classes must be in the same assembly and module.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create another partial class:

```
public partial class TanulmanyokEntities : ITanulmanyokEntities
{
}
```

This way, I didn't have to mess with the generated code.